# Ask db information every tot seconds

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, web

I'm trying to refresh data on my web page according to the data stored in the database, so every 2 seconds I call with an ajax request a php file. The called php script is this:

```
session_start();

.....Connection to the db.......

$prova = pg_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM maxdistance");

$prova2 = "";
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($prova)) {
     $prova2 = $prova2.$row[0].$row[1].$row[2];
}

$_SESSION['prova'] = $prova2;
```

And this is the code in javascript:

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
  newPositions();
}, 2000);

function newPositions(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "realTimePosition.php",
                      success: function(msg){
                          provaaa = <?php echo ($_SESSION[prova]); ?>;
                      }
                })
   });
```

The problem is that, when I refresh the page the code run and in the variable provaaa is stored the value 20 (the actual value in the db) but if I modify the value in the db, the value of the variable is the same, why is this happening?

Comment: you have to respond with the new value, session alone won't do that

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs in the browser, where PHP generates your JS file, performing all the replacements it needs to, and _then it dies_ as it's supposed to. The browsers gets that entirely PHP-free JS file, and runs that code on the user's computer. If you want the page to update, you will need to make your JS call your PHP server every two seconds to ask for that information. For instance, by using a dedicated `get_provaaa.php` that only echos whatever the current value in the db is. On the PHP side, that task should _only_ happen on request, not preemptively.

Answer (score 0):

you cant mix JS and PHP like this

problem part

```php
 provaaa = <?php echo ($_SESSION[prova]); ?>;
```

solution

- your PHP script have to send back REPLY with "echo"

```php
echo json_encode([ 'data' => $prova2]);
```

- then y have to catch server response inside your "success" callback dunction where param is RESPONSE from server so

```js
success: function(res){
                          provaaa = JSON.parse(res).data;
                      }
```

Comment: but what if I want to return multiple values from my php file?